# Induction Motor circuit

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, induction-motor, electric-machine

[image]

Can anyone please help me in understanding the problem. I am not able to figure what he is trying to ask.

I know one thing for sure, this problem only checks one thing that "Induction motor have high starting current"

EDIT

I am trying to attempt an explanation. Please check this

As supply is connected, high current starts flowing through G to IM which blows G.

Now, switch S is closed. Again high current starts flowing through S to IM. R gets supply across its terminals and glows continuosly.

Is this fine ??

Comment: Burns means ? lights up or blows off ?

Comment: Hint: what voltage will be across the G lamp if S is closed?

Comment: aren't (b) and (c) pretty much the same thing ... ?

Comment: @MITURAJ I have no idea...this is the complete question

Comment: Are there related questions that provide information about the rated current of the motor compared to the rated current and voltages of the lamps. I would assume that the lamps draw very much less current than the motor and are rated to operate on the supply voltage.

Comment: Charles Crown Sir, this is the complete problem. That assumption of yours makes things very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helpful hints:

1. What voltage will be across the G lamp if S is closed?

Your Edit 1:

> As supply is connected, high current starts flowing through G to IM which blows G.

No. G will limit the current. After all, it can be assumed that it is designed to run directly from the supply.

> Now, switch S is closed. Again high current starts flowing through S to IM. R gets supply across its terminals and glows continuosly.

Good.

> why is R not glowing when S is open ?? Is it because it is not getting rated voltage?

- If the motor wasn't there then what percentage of the voltage would each lamp get?
- If the motor is there will R get more or less voltage?

> If motor was not there then V/2......motor is there then < V/2.

Correct.

Comment: why is R not glowing when S is open ?? Is it because it is not getting rated voltage ?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: If motor was not there then V/2......motor is there then <V/2

Comment: low motor winding resistance in parallel with high resistance of lamp. Hence very low voltage across the lamp.

Comment: If he would have made a resistor in place of induction motor I would have solved it on my own. Anyways... Thanks @Transistor